# Dojo charting: Can i change the color of the line based on the value?

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

I have a working chart with Dojo 1.8.

```
chart1 = new dojox.charting.Chart2D("chart1");
chart1.addPlot("default", {type: "Lines", ...
chart1.addSeries("Series A", [{ x: 1, y: 2.3, tooltip: "Value 1"}, ...
```

My data from the series gets displayed correctly as line and the whole line (series) gets the color 'Green'.
I know how to change the color for the whole series, but would it be possible that the line changes its color based on the data values? Lets assume the x-axis is a time axis and I need the line (series) to be green for until today, and then red for the future values.
Would this be possible and how ?
(I am using markers for the values. If these could change based on the value it would be enough)

I found something something like this in the documentation:

```
chart.addSeries("Series A", [
    {y: 4, color: "red"},
    {y: 2, color: "green"},
    {y: 1, color: "blue"},
    {y: 1, text: "Other", **color: "white", fontColor: "red"**}
]);
```

But it only works for PIE-charts and not for LINES-charts.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this http://jsfiddle.net/jUS54/

Use styleFunc in the addPlot method for change the markers colors:

```
 var chart1 = new Chart("simplechart");
    chart1.addPlot("default", {type: Lines, markers:true, styleFunc: function(item {
    if(item <= 2){ 
      return { fill : "red" };
    }else if(item > 3){
      return { fill: "green" };
    }
    return {};
  }});
```

Comment: What if I need the color based on something else than item value?

Comment: @Petr on the function next to styleFunc you can pass any object that you have declared in your code. Do you have an example of the value that you nedd to use so I can create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color by adding 'fill' to your chart data. Basically, loop through your input data deciding what to set your fill too while constructing the JSON for chartData.

```
var chartData = [{y: 10000,fill: "red"},{y:9200,fill: "yellow"},{y:11811,fill: "green"},{y:12000,fill: "blue"},{y:7662,fill: "blue"},{y:13887,fill: "black"},{y:14200,fill: "gray"},{y:12222,fill: "purple"},{y:12000,fill: "green"},{y:10009,fill: "purple"},{y:11288,fill: "green"},{y:12099,fill: "blue"}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/goinoff/QnNk2/1/

Comment: Haven't tried it but change 'fill: "red"' to 'color: "red"' in data??